# state is not updating when the component re renders?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a Nextjs flashcard app. I'm passing a deck structure like this:

```
const deck = {
  title: 'React 101',
  flashcards: [flashcardOne, flashcardTwo],
};
```

as props to the `Deck` component. This component shows the first card in flashcards and a "next" button to increment the index and showing the next card in flashcards.
The `Card` component is very simple and shows the front and the back of the card depending of the state `front`.

This is what I got so far and it's working but if I click "next" when the card is showing the answer (`flashcard.back`), the next card is going to appear with the answer. And I'm not sure why, isn't the `Card` component re rendering when I click "next"? And if the component re renders, `front` is going to be set to true?

```
export default function Deck({ deck }) {
  const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0);
  const { title, flashcards } = deck;
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>{title}</h1>

        {cardIndex < flashcards.length ? (
          <>
            <div className={styles.grid}>
              <Card flashcard={flashcards[cardIndex]} />
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setCardIndex((cardIndex) => cardIndex + 1)}>
              Next
            </button>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div>End</div>
            <button>
              <Link href='/'>
                <a>Go to Home</a>
              </Link>
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => setCardIndex(0)}>Play again</button>
          </>
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export function Card({ flashcard }) {
  const [front, setFront] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      {front ? (
        <div
          className={`${globalStyles.card} ${styles.card}`}
          onClick={() => setFront(false)}
        >
          <p className={styles.front}>{flashcard.front}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div
          className={`${globalStyles.card} ${styles.card}`}
          onClick={() => setFront(true)}
        >
          <p className={styles.back}>{flashcard.back}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When state changes, the card will *re-render*, but it will not *re-mount*. So, existing state will not be reset.

Call `setFront(true)` when the flashcard prop has changed:

```
const [front, setFront] = useState(true);
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setFront(true);
}, [flashcard]);
```

I'm using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` to ensure `front` gets set ASAP, rather than after a paint cycle (which could cause flickering).

You can also significantly slim down the `Card` JSX:

```
export function Card({ flashcard }) {
  const [front, setFront] = useState(true);
  const face = front ? 'front' : 'back';
  return (
    <div
      className={`${globalStyles.card} ${styles.card}`}
      onClick={() => setFront(!front)}
    >
      <p className={styles[face]}>{flashcard[face]}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: OMG! I was just trying to find my code reference! LoL. And thanks, now I learnt something about `useLayoutEffect`!

Comment: `globalStyles.card + " " + styles.card` is smaller than `\`${globalStyles.card} ${styles.card}\`` right?

Comment: Both work fine, and the syntax looks OK to me either way. One could concatenate, or one could use template literals.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. One question, should be `onClick= {() => setFront((prevOpen) => !prevOpen)}` ?

Comment: @saralance That would work too, but it's not needed. since the outer `front` variable is visible at that point and you can just use `setFront(!front)`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I guess I had the same issue. Since you're using functional components, and you're re-using the same component or in better words, you're not unmounting and remounting the component really, you're just changing the props, this happens. For this, you need to do `useEffect()` and then `setFront(true)`.

Here's the code I used in my App.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setFront(true);
  }, [flashcard]);
```

This is what I have used in my [`Word.js`](https://github.com/praveenscience/Word-Bank/blob/4439f7ea106c375db41dac4717351605a56b208e/client/src/components/Screens/Welcome/Word.js#L11-L21) file.